# Como retornar o último caractere de uma String em C++?

Tags: c++, string

Quero fazer um programa que mostre na tela o último caractere de uma String. Em Python seria algo assim:

```py
nome = "Teste"
print(nome[-1])
```

**Resultado:**

> e

Então tentei adaptar isso para o C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    string nome="teste";
    cout<<nome[-1]<<endl;
       
    return 0;
}
```

E no final ele não mostrou nada.

Então como eu poderia fazer para exibir o último caractere de uma String em C++?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

C++ não tem essa sintaxe. Use [`back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back). Sempre olhe a documentação do que está usando para descobrir o que tem disponível para esse objeto. E note que esse método te dá o caractere por referência e não por cópia como Python faz, então pode não ser o que deseja em algumas situações, mas pode ser a melhor opção. Nem pense em converter código de uma linguagem para outra, não é só sintaxe que muda, não é capricho que existem várias linguagens, há uma mudança importante.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string nome = "teste";
   cout << nome.back() << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3i5jGi). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/usfkwbur-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/LastChar.cpp).

Outra opção é usar o [`rbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) que é o iterador, ele sozinho entrega justamente o último elemento da coleção, que é o caso de uma `string`. Com ele pode fazer uma cópia do caractere facilmente. Novamente precisa ver a documentação para uso correto já que ele devolve um ponteiro. De uma certa forma ele é mais interessante porque ele não aceita só o equivalente a -1, aceita outros caracteres olhando ao contrário.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string nome = "teste";
   cout << *nome.rbegin() << endl;
}
```

Por último pode pegar fazendo o que Python faz que é usar a matemática e uma informação adicional que não aparece na sintaxe, ou seja, pega o tamanho e adiciona o valor que usou como índice (sim, adiciona, mas como ele é negativo, acaba subtraindo):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string nome = "teste";
   cout << nome[nome.length() - 1] << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nh487E). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/ftnhmgsrnr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/LastChar2.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método [`std::string::back()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/back/). Leia mais detalhes sobre ele no link da documentação.

Note que C++ não tem a mesma sintaxe de Python e, por isso, seu código não funciona.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nome = "teste";
    cout << nome.back() << endl;   
    return 0;
}
```